# how to get the ID of an xml file node while editing it

Tags: xml

I'm editing my xml file with "XML Notepad"

I'm just trying to see the ID of a node. I have one of the nodes that contains extra elements compaired to the other nodes. The ID of the node is returned with the error message, but when I open the xml file I can't tell wich one is the node I want.

Is there a way to see the ID of the node when editing the file?

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by "ID"? Unless an attribute of XML type `id` has been provided, XML doesn't have that concept. What's the error message actually displaying?

Comment: [SSIS.Pipeline] Error: component "Source Item" (44137) failed the prepare phase and returned error code 0xC02092B0.

Comment: Unless that number appears in your XML file, it isn't an "XML id" and you'll need to work with whoever authored that code to figure out what it's referring to.